# Migrating from MBA 2013 to Mac Mini Mid 2011 using Carbon Copy Cloner

Tags: time-machine, migration

I've been using my 2013 MBA for music production using Logic Pro X, and I've downloaded all the additional Apple content for it. Also, the MBA has a few other apps and docs I use.

I've recently bought a mid 2011 Mac Mini, and installed Mavericks on there, then I went ahead and used Time Machine on the MBA to create a backup, and then I used that backup on the Mac Mini, so that I could have all the apps and content (esp. Logic's content) available on the Mac Mini, since I am starved for bandwidth here in South Africa.

Problem is that it Migration Assistant didn't restore any of the 35-odd GB of Logic Pro content on the Mac Mini, although I can see the content on the backup drive's file system.

Would I achieve my end result (full bootable 1:1 carbon copy of my MBA) on the Mac Mini if I use Carbon Copy Cloner?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

My experience with Carbon Copy Cloner, which I use for daily backups of my external drives and for monthly checksum backups, is that, yes, it will copy anything that you do not tell it to specifically exclude.

I'm wondering, however, if there is not a more simple way to do this; did you, by any chance, download the 'extras' directly from Apple, as opposed to from the Mac App Store, as a .pkg that you might have retained and, so, could simply reinstall? Many people had problems downloading the extras in the traditional manner and Apple made all (?) (most, at any rate) of those 'pro packs' available as a direct download from their site. The link I have for that download is:
http://audiocontentdownload.apple.com/lp10_ms3_content_2013/ProAudioCoreContent10.pkg

Comment: I'm going to try this link and report back.

Comment: Were those all or most of the plugins/components you were missing?

Answer (score 0):

'Bootable' might be the issue... it will certainly clone accurately, but whether that OS will be happy on the Mini I couldn't say. You may end up reinstalling the OS again over it to get the right kexts etc in place.

If you make sure that CCC adds a recovery partition, that might be relatively simple, but it's not something I've done myself, so I can't say for certain.